# What is Reset state of GPIOs on Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, compute-module

I want to use Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 to control some 24V Outputs.
I am using [MAX14912 Driver](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14912-MAX14913.pdf).

I want to asure that Raspberry does not turn the output on during booting process.

According to [BCM2711 Datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf),at reset, all GPIO pins are configured as inputs (GPFSEL0 Register has reset value = 0x0) with pulldowns enabled (GPIO_PUP_PDN_CNTRL_REGX has value = 0x2).

[image: GPFSELx Register]

[image: GPIO_PUP_PDN_CNTRL_REG0 Register]

I don't understand this sentence from Datasheet:

**The Alternate function table also has the pull state which is applied after a power down.**

What is the meaning of Pull column in this table? Does it mean that booter changes this values during the booting process (values from Device tree and config.txt)?

[image: Alternative functions]

I measured the values at PINS after the system is up and I got values from the table.

But during booting i got this:

yellow - 3v3

green - GPIO4

orange - GPIO26

[image: Oscillocsope startup]

I understand it so:

All pins go high for couple of ms, than low (probably because of pulldowns) and than low/high (depending on Devicetree/config settings)

I don't understand why they all go high during.

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 2):

The table shows the default pulls which are applied by the hardware when the Pi is powered after being powered down.

Answer (score 2):

On boot ALL pins are INPUT. A few (1-9 from memory) have pull-ups, others pull-down.

Shortly after power is applied pins are modified by Device Tree as configured in config.txt. It is possible to change pin state at this stage.